# set min length to fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

hi am new to sql can anyone help me with it.

I want to create a field example code date_type int auto increment with min size 9
that is that number should be 000000001,000000002...000000010....

Comment: Couldn't you just use a 1,2,3 field and then format it as 000000001, etc when you display it? The computer won't know the difference, and neither will humans!

Comment: if it is auto increment, it doesn't need to have a min size.

Answer (score 0):

Use ZEROFILL. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE zerofill_test (f1 INT(4) ZEROFILL,f2 INT(4));
INSERT INTO zerofill_test VALUES ( 1, 1 ), (10000, 10000);
```

Here f1 is defined with 'ZEROFILL' of 'int' type and f2 is simple `int`.
When data is selected with `SELECT` command it shows you the desired result.

```
SELECT * FROM zerofill_test;
 +-------+-------+
 | h     | m     |
 +-------+-------+
 |  0001 |     1 |
 | 10000 | 10000 |
 +-------+-------+
```

For you purpose, the size of int field should be 9 i.e. `date_type int(9) ZEROFILL'

Comment: And one more thing. ZEROFILL will convert the int field to unsigned.